# Advanced Custom Widget

Tags: android, android-widget, custom-controls

I googled a lot and spent many hours trying to figure out how to create custom Android UI widgets (in code and xml). But there are some limitations I don't know how to bypass. Therefore I mocked up an imaginary button and would like to know how to implement it.

This would help me a lot and I'm sure that I'm not the only one that has problems creating custom Android widgets.

[image]

Comment: I think it is doable using some LinearLayouts and ImageButtons. No need for custom widgets

Comment: What about the two color background from bottom left to top right and round corners?

Comment: Using [shape drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape), `rounded corners` are doable for sure. For the two colors, shape does support `gradient` but I'm not sure if you could make the colors edge that sharp.

Comment: Only smooth gradients are possible as fare as I know from playing around with it.

Comment: Did you consider using an image instead of drawing a sharp gradient?

Comment: Using an image results in >>overdrawing<< the round corners + the usual problems of resizing a large (width) image.

Answer (score 2):

About the multi-colored background, I was successful at these using shape drawables.

For example to define a grey solid zone, then a gradient transitioning to black, and a black solid zone:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="10px" />
        <solid android:color="#FF444444"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:left="45dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:centerX="15%"
        android:startColor="#FF444444"
        android:centerColor="#FF000000"
        android:endColor="#FF000000"
        android:type="linear"/>
    </shape>
</item>
    <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="10px" />
        <stroke
            android:width="2px"
            android:color="#FF444444" />
        <solid android:color="#00000000"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

The cool thing here is the layered shapes (*items*). It should allow you to define a yellow triangle, a red triangle, and a green rectangle.

The above layout renders into the following:
[image: snapshot]

(the icons and text not being rendered by the above layout)

Comment: 'layer-list' can't create triangles. The other problem is from the mock-up above, that I don't know how to create a round button like box that has a stroke and two colors in it (no gradient). If I set a background color on an inner view it will overdraw the layouts round corners.If I use two layouts with two different shape items, the separator line (mock-up) would be twice as thick as I desire (2x stroke width).

Comment: I got the round corners using 2 drawables: the one with the round corners and stroke outline, which actually uses the layer-list drawable _as background_. Concerning the triangles, I think I would try with linear gradients (in diagonal), with a sharp transition. This would probably do the trick ?

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to create a custom widget I recommend to check out a most similar standard widget from the android sources and modify them

Comment: Thats what I usually do. But how to have a bg like in the mock-up above and round corners? I can use a 'shape' and tell it to have round corners but I can't have a custom bg (as fare as I know) and round corners. As the bg goes from the bottom left to top right I can't user a 'NinePatch'. When I started to tinker around I thought too, that can't be that hard, but I'm currently not able to solve this problem.

Comment: You can do anything in an owner drawn View (onDraw). The Canvas supports common drawing primitives and also "Shapes".

Comment: I played around with canvas too. It's quite time consuming to draw UI elements yourself (figuring out how to - most tutorials in the web cover only the basic stuff). Its easy to draw a round rectangle with four corners, but if you only want two??? Also you get the problem with the UI measurement. In the end using onDraw resulted for me in being not practicable.

Comment: It is probably your only chance to learn about Canvas and co. Drawing just 2 rounded corners could be achieved by clipping away the other. However, if you find an other way, just take it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a shape for background:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
   <solid android:color="@color/GREEN"/>
   <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/GREEN"/>
</shape>
```

Then Create a shape with **layer-list** that show your image:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/GREEN"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="15dp"
        android:top="15dp"
        android:right="15dp"
        android:bottom="15dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_image" />
</layer-list>
```

Finally, you can use above shapes in a button:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFavorite"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/btnWorkout"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_main_button"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/shape_favorite"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/favorite"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_7"
        android:textColor="@color/ORANGE"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>
```

Even, it should mentioned that you can use first shape as a selector.